Downwash vs Finite-Wing Downwash
Is there a distinction to be made between downwash created due to lift generation of an infinite wing or airfoil and the "induced downwash" created due to a finite wing. I've been thinking of this additional downwash due to lift as an increment to the existing downwash. Is this a helpful way to think about it?

This answer should help.
